# Adding jquery and custom scripts to a Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Doing some searching through Google, I came across the same bit of code over and over for adding jQuery to a from-scratch Wordpress theme.

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/theme.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
```

I've added this code to my functions.php file, and I created a js folder and made a theme.js file using the following syntax in it:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
});
```

When I refresh my WP site, the theme.js file doesn't seem to be called. In Chrome Dev tools, it's not listed among the js files being rendered.

Am I using an outdated approach? How can I make my /js/theme.js file, using jquery, work for my theme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, [**`wp_enqueue_scripts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) only runs on the frontend, so you don't need the `is_admin()` check.

Second, only de-register the default jQuery (bundled with WP) [***if you really know what you are doing***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45437/including-jquery-and-jquery-files-the-correct-way). In your example, you are loading an outdated version from Google (current is 1.8.3, not 1.7.1). Also, see: [Don’t Dequeue WordPress’ jQuery](http://eamann.com/tech/dont-dequeue-wordpress-jquery/)

Third, you should be using [**`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), which is the correct function that will count for parent and child theme folders.

Finally, this code works ok in `/themes/my-theme/functions.php`:

```
add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_js_so_14864221", 11 );

function my_js_so_14864221() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script( 
        'my_script', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/theme.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ), 
        '1.0', 
        true
    );
}
```

And your jQuery code in theme.js should be encapsulated like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
    // $('#your-stuff').animate().hide().whatever();
});
```