# Including a jQuery plugin inside of WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am currently converting my HTML into a WordPress Site. The site uses the '`inview`' jQuery plugin.

I can't seem to be able to get it working within WordPress.

I have inserted the plugin link inside of the header.php: `src="js/jquery.inview.js"`

and the following in the `footer.php`:

```
<script type="text/jscript">
$('#seoHomeImage, #socialBar').bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
if (visible) {
$(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
} else {
$(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 });
}
});
</script>
```

I also have this from **Chris Coyiers Blank** theme, in the functions:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"), false);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Do I have to somehow link the '`inview`' plugin inside the functions page?

Thanks for looking :-)

Comment: Is there any console output. Maybe the order of script loading is messed up.

Comment: I cannot mark this one as duplicate because [the other one in not accepted and doesn't have any upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14864221/1287812). But the Answer is exactly the same as I would provide here. In short: don't de-register WP bundled jQuery & use the correct hook to enqueue & add jQuery as a dependency of your own script.

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code into document.ready section when DOM is finished event

```
    $(function () {
        $('#seoHomeImage, #socialBar').bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
            if (visible) {
                $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
            } else {
                $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 0 });
            }
        });
    });
```